# Modify an excel macro to look at whole column instead of single cell

Tags: vba, excel

Hello  I have a macros that looks at text on sheet1 and looks at a list of words on sheet2. if there are any matching words from sheet2 on sheet1, the words will turn red.  How do i modify my below macros so that it looks at all the text in column A not just A3, i keep getting error when using Range("A:A").  Also, how do i make this macros not take into consideration of lower and upper case?  ex: the word "test" is in the wordbank so if "test" was in sheet1, it would be highlighted but not the word "Test".

```
Sub wordbank()
Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
For Each c In ws2.Columns(1).SpecialCells(2)
    l = Len(c.Value)
    p = InStr(1, LCase(ws1.[A3].Value), LCase(c.Value))
    Do Until p = 0
        With ws1.[A3]
        b = Asc(.Characters(Start:=p - 1, Length:=1).Text)
        a = Asc(.Characters(Start:=p + l, Length:=1).Text)
        If (a < 97 Or a > 122) And (b = 32 Or b = 34) Then _
          .Characters(Start:=p, Length:=l).Font.Color = vbRed
            p = InStr(p + l + 1, .Value, c.Value)
       End With
    Loop
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You would put in another loop to loop though A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this: (untested)

```
Sub wordbank()
Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
For Each c In ws2.Columns(1).SpecialCells(2)
    l = Len(c.Value)
    For Each cel in ws1.Columns(1).SpecialCells(2)
        p = InStr(1, LCase(cel.Value), LCase(c.Value))
        Do Until p = 0
            With cel
              b = Asc(.Characters(Start:=p - 1, Length:=1).Text)
              a = Asc(.Characters(Start:=p + l, Length:=1).Text)
              If (a < 97 Or a > 122) And (b = 32 Or b = 34) Then _
                .Characters(Start:=p, Length:=l).Font.Color = vbRed
                p = InStr(p + l + 1, .Value, c.Value)
            End With
        Loop
    Next cel
Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: this is awesome, you are a beast!

Comment: actually it looks like now im getting an error again. It seems like as I add more words to my wordbank, it throws a "Invalid procedure call or argument" error.

Comment: for example, try pasting the phrase "this is a test" on sheet 1 and on the word bank add the words "this", "is", "a", "test".  run the macros and it works fine. go back to wordbank and add a new word like "this" which doesnt exist on sheet 1, if you run the macros it will display the error I mentioned above